# why there is so much space between the line and the actual flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, display

[image: see that free space??]

I don't really know whats going wrong here. I tried to make each username stand in parallel with the platform using flex properties, I tried looking for it in some sites, tutorials, but they don't explain anything about how to use flex display to sort such information.
If anyone could help please reach out, I'd really really appreciate it. Thank you.

```css
body{
    background-color:lightgray;
}

#boxbg{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 18%;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: lightgray;
    border: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width:600px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
#personpic{
    
position: relative;
bottom: 110px;
}
#title {
    color: rgb(79, 144, 209);
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 135px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}

#subtitle{
    color: grey;
    opacity: 90%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 155px;
    font-size: larger;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
}
#line{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    bottom: 160px;
    left: 45px;
}
.flexboxlinks{
    display: flex;
}

.facebook{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.facebookl{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.twitter{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.twitterl{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.linkedin{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
.linkedinl{
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
}
#aplus{
    position: relative;
    left: 520px;
    bottom: 230px;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    opacity: 80%;
    border: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgb(73, 175, 234);
    height: 29px;
    width: 29px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: rgb(73, 175, 234);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Yacine Bendjebbar">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>TRINING</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="boxbg">
        <img src="person-blue-shirt.png" id="personpic">
        <h2 id="title">Yacine Bendjebbar</h2>
        <p id="subtitle">Front-End Web Developer</p>
        <div id="line"></div>
        <div class="flexboxlinks">
            <div class="facebook">Facebook</div>
            <div class="facebookl">YacineBend2016</div>
            <div class="twitter">Twitter</div>
            <div class="twitterl">nate_mugiwara</div>
            <div class="linkedin">LinkedIn</div>
            <div class="linkedinl">yacinebendjebbar</div>
        </div>
        <div id="aplus">A+</div>
    

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML code pls ? Difficult to help you without it

Comment: i edited the question , there is the html code.

Comment: I highly recommend this Flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Try adding `flex-direction: column;` on `.flexboxlinks` and also add in the `</div>` closing tag you're missing on the `#boxbg` div. There's a lot of stuff going on in your code, but we can't help you fix all the issues. You're doing good so far, but I think you need to get more comfortable with the fundamentals of CSS/HTML, before getting into more advanced stuff like flexbox.

Comment: UPDATE : still the same problem ...

Comment: @yacinebendjebbar At first glance, adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.flexboxlinks` will make the text wrap onto a new row and the overflow won't occur.

Comment: that still doesn't do it @ths